# if jquery links are being added in header.php of wordpress theme is it effect the SEO?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, seo

If my jquery is being added in my header files (WP). these are more then 8 to 10 files being included in header. Is it have any impact on SEO of my site ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The impact is not because you use it in your header. it's recommended that you don't use it in your header because any javascript in header makes your website slower and for a website, being slow is most harmful thing you can ever done.

http://moz.com/search-ranking-factors

look at the "Response Time of Page in Seconds" at the bottom.

you can place your javascript files at the bottom of your website before  tag.